# Make variants based on alphabet-number junction in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words, some of which are single words, some multi-word and the words may or may not have digit characters.

An example -

`word_list=['word', 'kap1','another word', 'another-1 word', 'another word 1']`

I want to identify single-word entries in the list, of the form -

`alphabets*Junction*digit(s)`

where **Junction** can be either space, or hyphen or nothing. For example in the list above, `kap1` qualifies (and no other entry does). Now, having found this entry, I want to create variants (based on the junction) of this entry, and add them to the list.

So for example, having found `kap1`, I want to add `kap 1` and `kap-1` to the list.

I was able to write the initial regex for identifying the entries -

`Word_NumberRegex=re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z]+[ -]?\d+$")`

but I wanted to know a good algorithm for the creation of the variants, depending on the junction.

Comment: The `A-z` range doesn't contain only letters, see the ASCII table.

Comment: Use this regex [`^([a-zA-Z]+)[- ]?(\d+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/sDMaAt/1/)  to validate and grab 2 values in 2 captured groups. Later use these 2 values to create variants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re`, you can capture the matched patterns, and reformat with customized separators:

```
word_list=['word', 'kap1','another word', 'another-1 word', 'another word 1']

import re    
p = r'([a-zA-Z]+)[- ]?([0-9]+)'
[re.sub(p, r'\1{}\2'.format(sep), w) for w in word_list if re.fullmatch(p, w) for sep in ['', ' ', '-']]

# ['kap1', 'kap 1', 'kap-1']
```

Precompile the pattern:

```
p = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+)[- ]?([0-9]+)')
[p.sub(r'\1{}\2'.format(sep), w) for w in word_list if p.fullmatch(w) for sep in ['', ' ', '-']]
​
# ['kap1', 'kap 1', 'kap-1']
```

Comment: if instead of `kap1`, the list had `kap-1`, then the output should have been `['kap1','kap 1']`. Your program gives `['kap 1', 'kap-1']`

Comment: You can add an empty string to the separators if you want all three variants.

Comment: i was thinking more like, if the word has one of the separators, then the code should give me the *other two* variants, but I guess I can just remove the duplicate later

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3 **capturing groups** and use the middle group to capture *junction* character. Use *junction* character to search a list of separators and get your desired output:

```
import re

word_list=['word', 'kap1', 'another word', 'abc-123', 'another-1 word', 'another word 1']

reg = re.compile(r'^([a-zA-Z]+)([- ]?)([0-9]+)$')

for w in word_list:
   m = reg.match(w)
   if m:
      result = []
      seps = ['', ' ', '-']
      seps.remove(m.group(2))
      for s in seps:
         result += [m.group(1) + s + m.group(3)]
      print result
```

**Output:**

```
['kap 1', 'kap-1']
['abc123', 'abc 123']
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/qGcdA3)

Comment: i think you should have the `seps = ['', ' ', '-']` inside the for loop, because currently you permanently `remove` elements from the `seps` list, so the code will not work properly if there were more than one matching words in the word_list